# Printing out end sum after executing for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is a simple for loop i just want to declare a variable storing the final value of sum which can be used outside the for loop.Just printing cout<<sum;(outside for loop) gives an error that variable sum was not declared in this scope.

```
for (int score=1,sum=0;score<6;score++){

             int required;

             cin >> required;

            sum+=required;

            cout << sum << endl;
    }
```

Comment: You are declaring the int inside of the for loop if you want to access it outside of the for loop declare it outside of the for loop.

Comment: The error message seems clear. If you need `sum` outside the `for` it needs to be declared outside the `for`.

Comment: can someone give a detail answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int score=1;score<6;score++){

         int required;

         cin >> required;

        sum+=required;

}
cout << sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop

```
for (int score=1,sum=0;score<6;score++){
    int required;
    cin >> required;
    sum+=required;
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

is equivalent to the following code:

```
{
    int score=1,sum=0;
    while (score<6){
        int required;
        cin >> required;
        sum+=required;
        cout << sum << endl;

        score++;
    }
}
```

Note especially the outer block, which places the variables `score` and `sum` inside it, making it available only for the loop.

Comment: I just shared a segment of my program which gave an error the code is much larger than this so i prefer not to use a while loop.I knew my segment of for loop can be coded using while loop.But Anyways Thanks.

Comment: @NoobCoder1809 I don't mean that you should replace your `for` loop with a `while` loop, I only show how the `for` loop will be translated and how the scoping of the variables will be.

Comment: On point @Some programmer dude You were on point it was a correct and detailed explaination this method of using a while loop is correct and talking about scoping of the variables you got me a correct explanation on that .The declaration of the two int variables were correct i would keep that in mind.Thanks i greatly appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this error, you should have good understanding about Scope of Variables in C++.

There are mainly two types of variable scopes:

1. Local Variables

Variables defined within a function or block are said to be local to those functions.

- Anything between ‘{‘ and ‘}’ is said to inside a block.
- Local variables do not exist outside the block in which they are declared, i.e. they can not be accessed or used outside that block.
- Declaring local variables: Local variables are declared inside a block.

2.Global Variables

As the name suggests, Global Variables can be accessed from any part of the program.

- They are available through out the life time of a program.
- They are declared at the top of the program outside all of the functions or blocks.
- Declaring global variables: Global variables are usually declared outside of all of the functions and blocks, at the top of the program. They can be accessed from any portion of the program.

Note: in your case you declared sum as local variable, this is the reason your are not able  to access out of scope.

Comment: Vivek Jain Yeah i know the concept of local and global variable just i was confused about how can i add 2 initializers(ie sum and score) during execution of a for loop.But i figured out that initializing it outside for loop also works.I came to know that for loop cam change the value of a variable assigned at the beginning of a function .But anyways Thank you.